# Running a Docker image in PyCharm causes "Invalid volume specification"

Tags: python, windows, docker, tensorflow, pycharm

I am trying to run a project based on a Docker Image (Tensorflow, following instructions from [this tutorial](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-install-and-run-tensorflow-on-a-windows-pc/)) as described in [this blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/). The Docker is running fine, but I'm unable to import it in PyCharm (professional, does not work in community version). I get the following error message:

> Error running main: Can't run remote python interpreter:
>   {"message":"Invalid bind mount spec
>   \"C:/Path-to-project/Project-name:/opt/project:rw\":
>   Invalid volume specification:
>   'C:/Path-to-project/Project-name:/opt/project:rw'"}

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Windows Linux path problem. To solve it, change project paths to the Docker file to `/c/Path-to-project/Project-name` (with a lower case c and forward slashes) in order to solve this problem. Inspired by [this link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/06/pycharm-2016-2-eap-4-build-162-1120/).

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem as follows:

1. Go to: `File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> Your docker interpreter -> Path mappings`;
2. Add row: `{'Local path': 'C:', 'Remote path': '/c'}` (replace to your drive with project; if you use this interpeter for several projects from differen drives then add them all);
3. Go to: `Run -> Edit Configurations -> Your configuration -> Docker container settings -> '...' -> Volume bindings`;
4. Select row with project's binding (example: `{'Container path': '/opt/project', 'Host path': 'C:\Users\_username_\my_python_project'}`) and press '**Edit**'.
5. Press `OK -> Apply -> OK`. If first '**OK**' without changes did not help then replace `'Host path': 'C:\Users\_username_\my_python_project'` to `'Host path': '/c/Users/_username_/my_python_project'`;
6. Run your python configuration.

**About**:

- Windows 10 1607 [10.0.14393]
- PyCharm 2016.2.3
- Build #PY-162.1967.10, built on September 7, 2016
- JRE: 1.8.0_102-b14 amd64
- JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Why PyCharm ignore `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Docker -> VirtualBox shared folders` in `Run -> Edit Configurations`?