# PyCharm Docker volume mounts work in Python run configuration, but not in Python tests run configuration

Tags: docker, pycharm

I've created two PyCharm run configurations for a new project I created. One as a `Python` run configuration and one as a `Python tests` (automatic) run configuration.

I've configured them as close to identially as possible. In the `Docker container settings` for both I have the following volume mount `--entrypoint -v /tmp:/tmp --rm`.

In the Python run configuration this volume mount works. I test it by adding a simple breakpoint on line 1 of my code and running `os.listdir('/tmp')` and see files from my host. In the Python tests run configuration the volume mount is not applied and I see files baked into the docker image.

This behavior suggests that the Docker container settings are being ignored in the Python tests run configuration, but I have not found any documentation or settings that could explain this discrepancy.

PyCharm 2022.1.3 (Professional Edition)

Other notes:

- I've run debug logs in pycharm but didn't note anything of interest.
- I've run GPT4 out of ideas.

Comment: Is it a path mapping issue as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39968174/6309)?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Pycharm seems particularly bad with Docker support.  Generally, it seems that you need to set up your containers to always have a project directory of /opt/projects if you don't want to spend a huge amount of time debugging their configurations.